# morphia Geo-spatial "near" method in embedded list

Tags: mongodb, playframework, morphia

I have the following data structure:

```
{ _id : ObjectId(...),
  name : "...",
  addresses : [ {
                 context : "home" ,
                 loc : [ 55.5, 42.3 ]
                } ,
                {
                 context : "home",
                 loc : [ -74 , 44.74 ]
                }
              ]
}
```

I create a object with a embedded list called "addresses".
Now I want to find all addresses in the list near to a given location with the geo-spatial query method "near" of morphia.

My problem is that I have to handle a embedded list and not a query. Is this possible with the "near method"?

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to query against `addresses.loc`.  We're wandering a little bit in to unfamiliar territory with this document structure for me but I pretty sure this will work.